# How to use python cgi code to search file and display in browser along with its name

Tags: python, html, browser, cgi

I have a simple html file with text input for file name. It will search the file in the folders and display contents in the browser using cgi script. The file can be pdf or image file. Wish to display '**file name as  well as the contents in the browser'**. Currently it displays either file name or contents but not both depending on Content type selected. Kindly guide. I need the exact code.

Comment: First you have to clarify what exactly you want to achieve. Can you give examples? Especially with PDF I don't know what you expect to see in the browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3815611/blackjack here is the code at this link which i need to improve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969251/how-to-display-pdf-file-contents-as-well-as-its-full-name-in-the-browser-using-c

Comment: So essentially you are asking the very same question here as in the linked question, but this time just with less details (code)!?